# option from with php/mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I'm stuck on a posting script, I want information from mysql table 'category' from name to put that in mysql table 'post' to cat.

I cant get the data from category table in my html form "$row['name']
So when I click on sumbit the name from table 'category' example category called by 'name' test will be inserted into $cat

```
    <html>
<body>
<title>ADD NEW POST</title>
<?php
// POST.PHP POSTING NEW CONTENT
include 'config.php';
// values from form
$id=$_POST['id'];
$title=$_POST['title'];
$pic=$_POST['pic'];
$youtube=$_POST['youtube'];
$cat=$_post['cat'];


// insert data to mysql
$sql="INSERT INTO post(id, pic, youtube, cat)VALUES('$id', '$title', '$pic', '$youtube', '$cat')";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

// succes added
if($result){

echo "Added a new post";
}

else {
echo "SOMETHING WENT WRONG!";
}
// end of post script ^^

?> 

<?php
$query2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `category` ");



 while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query2)){

    }


// html form start ?>
<form action="<?php $_PHP_SELF ?>" method="post">
title: <input name="title" type="text" id="title"><br />
Picture link: <input name="pic" type="text" SIZE="80" id="pic"><br />
Youtube link: <input name="youtube" type="text" SIZE="80" id="youtube"><br />
Category game: <select name="name">
<option VALUE="<?php echo ''.$row['name'].''; ?>"><?php echo ''.$row['name'].''; ?></option>
<br /><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
</form>



</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

You are vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com). And if you have even bare bones minimal error handling in your code, you'd have been told WHERE the error is:

```
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^-- you **NEED** this
```

As for the actual problem:

```
$sql="
INSERT INTO post(id, pic, youtube, cat)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^--- FOUR fields
VALUES
('$id', '$title', '$pic', '$youtube', '$cat')";
 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^--- FIVE values
```

You're missing `title` in the field list.

Never **EVER** assume success. Assume everything will fail, code accordingly, and treat success as a pleasant surprise.

Comment: "and treat success as a pleasant surprise." hehehe his life will be only surpises :)

Comment: Very stupid of me:P I noticed later forgot to add title, just only did it in VALUES,

Comment: Still can't figure out, how to SELECT from db to option
`$query2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `category` WHERE `name`");


 while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query2)){
       $name = $row['name'];
    }`

this is from form
`<option VALUE="<?php echo "$name"; ?>"><?php echo "$name"; ?></option>`

Comment: your `while()` isn't DOING anything. you just fetch all the rows and throw them away.